# Stream multiple sound sources via mms/rtsp using pulseaudio

Tags: broadcast, streaming

I have a server with about 20 different sound capable applications.
Lets say each application gets a ID between 10 and 30.

I could then do it by launching each application by `padsp -s 127.0.0.1:99[ID] [application] [arguments]`

Now I would want some possibility to stream this via a apache server to the public. I need to have 30 pulseaudio servers alive which can stream audio to a client which connected to my HTTP server. Lets say a user points their streaming client to mms://my-server-adress.com/stream/25

Now that streaming server should take the sound from the pulseaudio server listening on port 9925 and stream that sound via mms/http to that client.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This question seems more broadcast and compression specific than AV Production! Inviting experts to a new site proposal [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) which aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.